# Unexpected character '`', but character is not in file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I run my code in staging environment using "rails s -e staging", I get the error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Unexpected character '`'):
[788647b2-7d6f-4d80-9820-ab477702e8af]     4: .panel_login
[788647b2-7d6f-4d80-9820-ab477702e8af]     5:   = form_for @user_session, :html => {:class => 'login_form'} do |f|
[788647b2-7d6f-4d80-9820-ab477702e8af]     6:     -# .head{:style => 'text-align:center;'}
[788647b2-7d6f-4d80-9820-ab477702e8af]     7:       -# .margin_bottom_20= image_tag('silk_app_logo.png')
[788647b2-7d6f-4d80-9820-ab477702e8af]     8:       -# .bold#page_title_login Silk Service Centre
[788647b2-7d6f-4d80-9820-ab477702e8af]     9:
[788647b2-7d6f-4d80-9820-ab477702e8af]    10:     %fieldset
[788647b2-7d6f-4d80-9820-ab477702e8af]
[788647b2-7d6f-4d80-9820-ab477702e8af] app/views/user_sessions/new.html.haml:7:in `block in _app_views_user_sessions_new_html_haml___3840161814571174569_70257985310040'
[788647b2-7d6f-4d80-9820-ab477702e8af] app/views/user_sessions/new.html.haml:5:in `_app_views_user_sessions_new_html_haml___3840161814571174569_70257985310040'
```

As you can see, the character is not in my code. The program also works fine on local. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

If I delete the line, I get the same error for the same line:

```
-------------------------------
Backtrace:
-------------------------------

  app/views/user_sessions/new.html.haml:7:in `block in _app_views_user_se=
ssions_new_html_haml___3840161814571174569_70257985310040'
  app/views/user_sessions/new.html.haml:5:in `_app_views_user_sessions_ne=
w_html_haml___3840161814571174569_70257985310040'



[4b6a81dd-71c7-4160-a431-bee39dc33475]
[4b6a81dd-71c7-4160-a431-bee39dc33475] ActionView::Template::Error (Unexpected character '`'):
[4b6a81dd-71c7-4160-a431-bee39dc33475]     4: .panel_login
[4b6a81dd-71c7-4160-a431-bee39dc33475]     5:   = form_for @user_session, :html => {:class => 'login_form'} do |f|
[4b6a81dd-71c7-4160-a431-bee39dc33475]     6:
[4b6a81dd-71c7-4160-a431-bee39dc33475]     7:     %fieldset
[4b6a81dd-71c7-4160-a431-bee39dc33475]     8:       .login_label Email Address
[4b6a81dd-71c7-4160-a431-bee39dc33475]     9:       .margin_bottom_20= email_field_tag 'user_session[email]', @user_session.email, :class => 'required form-control', :placeholder => 'Username', :id => 'login'
[4b6a81dd-71c7-4160-a431-bee39dc33475]    10:       .login_label Password
[4b6a81dd-71c7-4160-a431-bee39dc33475]
[4b6a81dd-71c7-4160-a431-bee39dc33475] app/views/user_sessions/new.html.haml:7:in `block in _app_views_user_sessions_new_html_haml___3840161814571174569_70257985310040'
[4b6a81dd-71c7-4160-a431-bee39dc33475] app/views/user_sessions/new.html.haml:5:in `_app_views_user_sessions_new_html_haml___3840161814571174569_70257985310040'
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably it is a control ascii characters or something like that, you can not see it, but actually it is in your code file.Try to delete the line and type a new line, see if it can solve this problem.

Comment: It wasn't that, it's commented out in the first block of code, and when I delete it, the error is still there for the same line. And it shouldn't work for local if it has that problem right?